# Hierarchical Query( how to retrieve middle nodes)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Good evening, I need help trying to retrieve the middle-class managers from one of my hierarchical tables (circled in red), who are not root node nor leaf node.

**Hierarchical chart/Data**
[image: Hierarchical Chart]
[image: Data]

I was able to retrieve all the leaf nodes using my query

```
select level,  first_name ||' '|| last_name "FullName" 
from more_employees
where employee_id not in (select NVL(manager_id, 0) from more_employees)
start with employee_id = 1
CONNECT by prior employee_id = manager_id;
```

[image: Result]

I'm sure I should use the keyword "in" in my where clause, but keep getting a different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CONNECT_BY_IS_LEAF` pseudo column for this.

```
select level,  first_name ||' '|| last_name "FullName" 
from more_employees
where connect_by_isleaf = 0 and manager_id is not null
start with employee_id = 1
connect by prior employee_id = manager_id;
```

You can also use that to get all leafs:

```
select level,  first_name ||' '|| last_name "FullName" 
from more_employees
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with employee_id = 1
connect by prior employee_id = manager_id;
```

Which is probably faster than your solution with a sub-select

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/511d9/2

Comment: Just curious. Why do you think it may be faster than subselect?

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: because only a single access to the table is needed. The sub-select results in two queries to the same table (I'm talking about the original query in the question to get all leafs, not your answer)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work I believe

```
select * from more_employees m1 where manager_id is not null
and exists ( select 1 from more_employees m2 where m2.manager_id=m1.employee_id)
```

Comment: This is the correct (and simplest) solution. "middle" nodes have a parent `where they point to`, and children that `point to them`. This is one of the few cases where you don't need recursion, only checking for "NULL pointers".